# Counting and Combinations Problem

Tags: combinatorics

How many three-digit numbers can be built from the digits in the following list: 2,3,5,5,5,6,6? The answer is 43, but I don't know how to get it. I thought it was $\displaystyle \frac{7!}{3!2!}$, but apparently not. Can someone explain this?

Comment: That's the number of $7$-digit numbers you can form from those digits.

Comment: no its just related

Comment: To what is your comment referring?

Comment: I'm referring to your comment

Comment: because the 7 digits 2355566 is different than 2365556

Comment: So you are saying $\frac{7!}{3!2!}$ is not the number of $7$-digit numbers formable by those digits?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20323/discussion-between-anonymous-and-thomas-andrews).

Comment: To comment on your thought, lets use letters. The number of permutations for the letters $abcde$ is $5!$. This is because every letter is different. In the case where the letters are $aabbc$ (including repeated letters) the number of permutations is $$\frac{5!}{2!2!}$$ which is equivalent to your answer but note that we're handling permutations, only rearrangements. Hence your answer was the number of $7$ digit numbers you can form with the list given (as Thomas Andrews pointed out).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number of three digit numbers consisting of the digits $2,3,5$ and $6$ is $4^3 = 64$

But some of these numbers are not allowed, more precisely thise who contain more than $2$ times the digit $6$ or more than one time the digit $2$ or $3$. It is convenient that these sets are disjoint.

There is only one number that contains more than 2 times the digit $6$ i.e. $666$.

Also, there are $9$ numbers that contian $2$ times the digit $2$ and one number that contains the digit $2$ three times. So in total 10 numbers. The same is true for the digit $3$.

So the total number of allowed numbers is $64 -1 -2 \times 10 = 43$